# How to send email using only the socket library in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, email, smtp

I am writing a client to send email from Python without using smtplib, yagmail, smtputil, flask-mail, etc.

I'm trying to attach a file to the email. I was able to encode and send `.txt` and `.docx` files, but when it comes to `.png` and `.jpg` files, my server does not show the file's encoding information, even though the code runs normally.

I already have my test server:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to attach `.png`, `.jpg`, `.pdf`, `.zip` files in to my email, here is my code:

```py
def get_attachment_content(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        base64_encoded = base64.b64encode(file_data)
        base64_encoded_str = base64_encoded.decode("utf-8")
        return base64_encoded_str

def guess_mime_type(file_path):
    # Một số kiểu MIME mặc định cho một số định dạng file phổ biến
    mime_types = {
        '.txt': 'text/plain',
        '.pdf': 'application/pdf',
        '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
        '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.doc': 'application/msword',
        '.docx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        '.zip': 'application/zip',
    }

    _, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)

    return mime_types.get(file_extension.lower(), 'application/octet-stream')

def generate_email_content(to, from_, subject, message, attachment_file_list, cc_recipients):
    boundary = ' ------ ' + str(time.time()) + ' ------ '
    email_content = ''
    email_content += f'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="{boundary}"\r\n'
    email_content += f"Message-ID: {generate_message_id()}\r\n"
    email_content += f'Date: {time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0700", time.localtime())}\r\n'
    email_content += f'User-Agent: VMS\r\n'
    email_content += f'To: {to}\r\n'
    
    if len(cc_recipients) > 1:
        email_content += f'CC: {", ".join(cc_recipients)}\r\n'
    
    email_content += f'From: {from_}\r\n'
    email_content += f'Subject: {subject}\r\n'
    email_content += f'\r\n{boundary}\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n{message}\r\n'

    if attachment_file_list:
        for attachment_path in attachment_file_list:
            attachment_content = get_attachment_content(attachment_path)
            mime_type = guess_mime_type(attachment_path)
            email_content += f'\r\n{boundary}\r\nContent-Type: {mime_type}\r\n'
            email_content += f'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n'
            email_content += f'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "{os.path.basename(attachment_path)}"\r\n\r\n{attachment_content}\r\n'

    email_content += f'{boundary}\r\n'

    return email_content
```

Comment: If you insist on implementing everything by your own then please study the relevant RFC 2045...2048 and RFC 5322. Just to mention the few things which are obviously wrong here: wrong use of boundary (both in definition and for separating parts), not adhering to limit of line length, not encoding non-ASCII headers, not encoding non-ASCII text, not encoding non-ASCII filename. The main point for your current problem is probably improper handling of boundary, but the rest of the problems will hunt you later. Do yourself a favor and use established libraries.

Comment: Also note that different email clients will differ on how they deal with invalid content. This means that if the content looks good in one client it does not mean that it is actually properly implemented nor that it will look good in another client too. That's why we have standards to follow instead of second-guessing what is expected from observing a few examples and then trying to make it somehow work for a selected clients.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your generated `boundary` correctly.

In the `Content-Type` header, the `boundary` attribute must specify just the value of the boundary, which you are doing.

But, in the actual email body, you need to *prefix* each opening boundary with `--` and *suffix* the closing boundary with `--`. You are not doing this!

Try this instead:

```py
def generate_email_content(to, from_, subject, message, attachment_file_list, cc_recipients):
    boundary = '------' + str(time.time()) + '------'
    email_content = ''
    email_content += f'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="{boundary}"\r\n'
    email_content += f"Message-ID: {generate_message_id()}\r\n"
    email_content += f'Date: {time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0700", time.localtime())}\r\n'
    email_content += f'User-Agent: VMS\r\n'
    email_content += f'To: {to}\r\n'
    
    if len(cc_recipients) > 0:
        email_content += f'CC: {", ".join(cc_recipients)}\r\n'
    
    email_content += f'From: {from_}\r\n'
    email_content += f'Subject: {subject}\r\n'
    email_content += f'\r\n'
    email_content += f'--{boundary}\r\n'
    email_content += f'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n'
    email_content += f'\r\n'
    email_content += message

    if attachment_file_list:
        for attachment_path in attachment_file_list:
            attachment_content = get_attachment_content(attachment_path)
            mime_type = guess_mime_type(attachment_path)
            email_content += f'\r\n--{boundary}\r\n'
            email_content += f'Content-Type: {mime_type}\r\n'
            email_content += f'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n'
            email_content += f'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "{os.path.basename(attachment_path)}"\r\n'
            email_content += f'\r\n'
            email_content += attachment_content

    email_content += f'\r\n--{boundary}--\r\n'

    return email_content
```